# Creating a publicly accessible RDS instance in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I'm totally throwing my hands up with this one.  I've been trying to create a publicly accessible RDS instance using CloudFormation.  I want to be able to connect to my instance via a mysql client.  When I deploy this stack it says that the instance is publicly accessible in the RDS console, but I can't connect to via the endpoint provided in the RDS console.  I'm guessing that I messed up/missed something with the VPC pieces.  He's my stack.yaml file:

```
Resources:
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: 'VPC created by cf'
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: Created By CF
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  DataSourceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Open database for access
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  DSSGIngressRule:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      FromPort: "3306"
      ToPort: "3306"
      GroupId: !Ref DataSourceSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref DataSourceSecurityGroup
  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/20
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
      CidrBlock: 10.0.16.0/20
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: 'RouteTable created by CF'
  RouteTable1Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  RouteTable2Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  InternetRouteRule:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  DataSourceSubtNetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: Created by CF
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet1
        - !Ref PublicSubnet2
  DataSource:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: '5'
      DBInstanceClass: db.m1.small
      DBName: MyDb
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DataSourceSubtNetGroup
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: AdminUser
      MasterUserPassword: AdminPassword
      PubliclyAccessible: true
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref DataSourceSecurityGroup
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the inbound security groups in Cloudformation.  Check whether it allows ingress from any CIDR block specially DataSourceSecurityGroup

Comment: Do you mean from VPC?

Comment: @Ashan, Do you mean to check in  VPC?  I don't see any way to check security groups in cloud formation.  I'm pretty fuzzy on how everything in VPC works. Could you be more specific?

Comment: First check from aws web console whether security groups are open for external access. Im in doubt the security groups in the CloudFormation are open to outside by using default values for ingress.

Comment: Why do you need the `RouteTable`, is attaching the internet gateway not enough?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your **DataSourceSecurityGroup** security group is currently configured as:

- Permit inbounded connections on Port 3306 from Security Group **DataSourceSecurityGroup**

That is, it will allow inbound connections from any Amazon EC2 instance that is itself a member of the DataSourceSecurityGroup security group.

If you wanted to allow access from **anywhere on the Internet**, then change your template to permit inbound access from `0.0.0.0/0`:

```
  DSSGIngressRule:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      FromPort: "3306"
      ToPort: "3306"
      GroupId: !Ref DataSourceSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

I made this change, tested your template and it worked fine.

For future reference: You can debug this type of thing by creating the stack and then examining the Security Group in the management console.

Comment: Thanks was exactly it. Thanks!